# How to use password hashing using BCrypt in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, bcrypt, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0

I have to use bCrypt hash generator for encrypting any string.

## Steps I have taken: #

1- Added Jar file in Lib folder 
2- Restarted the Jmeter 
3- Added below code in JSR223 Sampler

```
String password = "1234"; 
String bcryptHashString = BCrypt.withDefaults().hashToString(10, password.toCharArray());
```

- Exception Received

2023-10-06 13:27:53,749 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BCrypt for class: Script228
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: BCrypt for class: Script228
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:71) ~[groovy-jsr223-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_381]
at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72) [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to copy and paste the necessary [`import` statement](https://groovy-lang.org/structure.html#_imports)

```
import at.favre.lib.crypto.bcrypt.BCrypt
```

[image]

also you need to add file**s**, not the **file**, bcrypt won't work without [bytes](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/at.favre.lib/bytes) utility library

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)